# Modifying Woocommerce menu based on tags and categories

Tags: menus, filters

I am currently trying to modify/customize a primary menu on Woocommerce. The products ghave tags X and are categorized in categories Y. I’d like to have a way to filter products on Woocommerce directly from menu, so if I choose submenu item Y from menu item X, the store will only show items with X tag in category Y.

The current menu building options don’t seem to provide such options.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, so you want to add categories to the menu? Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: I'd like to add both, categories and tags. For example, I have a menu item "kids" (a product tag) and submenu item "hats" (a product category), so if I choose that, only products with a tag of "kids" in category "hats" are shown.